# Welche Schreibweise ist korrekt "Es schneite in rauen Mengen" oder "Es schneite in rauhen Mengen"

Tags: spelling

[Duden-Online](http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/rauhen) verrät, dass beim Wort "rauh" die Rechtschreibreform zugeschlagen hat und es jetzt "rau" heißt. Anderseits hat man der Form [aufrauhen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/aufrauhen) ihr "h" gelassen.

[Woxikon](http://rechtschreibung.woxikon.de/schreibweise/in%20rauhen%20mengen.php) nennt Korrekte Schreibweise:

> in rauhen Mengen

in einigen Tageszeitungen ([BZ](http://www.berliner-zeitung.de/berlin/zwischenbilanz-berliner-winter--wir-haben-noch-alles-in-rauen-mengen-,10809148,11446210.html) und [Blick.CH](http://www.blick.ch/news/schweiz/eingeschneit-192637) finde ich

> in rauen Mengen

Welches ist jetzt die korrekte Schreibweise und wurde sie gegebenenfalls geändert?

Answer (score 4):

Da die neue Schreibweise "[rau](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufrauen)" lautet, fehlt auch bei der Mehrzahlvariante des Adjektivs das "h" (sofern die neue Rechtschreibung verwendet wird). Also:

> in rauen Mengen

Es gibt beim Duden auch keinen eigenen Eintrag für "aufrauhen", nur noch für "[aufrauen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/aufrauhen)".

Siehe auch:

"[in rauen Mengen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/rauen+Mengen)" vs. "[in rauhen Mengen](http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/in+rauhen+Mengen)" (15:0)

Comment: Dann scheint Duden zu Duden-Online inkonsistent zu sein. In Duden-Online steht aufrauhen  bei den Beispielen zur neuen Rechtschreibung http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/aufrauhen.

Comment: Nein, [*aufrauhen* steht in der Duden Liste zur alten Rechtschreibung.](http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/beispiele-zur-neuen-rechtschreibung/2)

Comment: @Takkat ich denke "aufrauhen" verdient eine eigene Frage, da Duden-Online http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/aufrauhen vermutlich falsch ist. Vgl http://www.ids-mannheim.de/service/reform/ Hier sollte wir nur noch herausfinden, ob "In rauhen Mengen" nach alter Rechtschreibung korrekt war oder nicht.

Comment: @bernd_k: Duden-Online ist hier eindeutig und *nicht* im Widerspruch mit IDS. "rauh" mit allen Abwandlungen (rauhen, aufrauhen, ...) ist alte, "rau" mit allen Abwandlungen (rauen, aufrauen, ...) ist neue Rechtschreibung.

Comment: @john Ich sehe da eindeutig einen nicht als solchen gekennzeichneten Eintrag in alter Rechtschreibung und das ist dann wohl eindeutig falsch.

Comment: @bernd_k: Vielleicht ist es Dir nicht bewusst, aber Dein Link zeigt nur ein Vorschau dieser Seite: http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/beispiele-zur-neuen-rechtschreibung/7 - In der Vorschau wird keine Tabellendarstellung unterstützt.